# how to use accessibility in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

does anyone know how to make the voice over to read something that has no text using accessibility? for example, if you go on an image it reads a description, or if you go on a back button it would say back button.
I have tried the tooltip but that is not working and that is not what I'm looking for. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the [Semantics](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Semantics-class.html) widget. For descriptions of the properties passed into the constructor of Semantics take a look at the [SemanticsProperty](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/semantics/SemanticsProperties-class.html) class.